# How to call a <form fileSelected()> in JS

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons that use standard file upload functionality and I need help with how to convert these calls to JavaScript:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=""     style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:200px;margin:0;background-color:transparent;">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="10" bgcolor="transparent" align="center" valign="middle">
                <div>
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="width:70px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;background-color:transparent;"accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" onchange="fileSelected();">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10" bgcolor="transparent" align="center" valign="middle">
                <iframe src="../work7/uploadfr.htm" name="uploadframe" width="10"     height="10" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" id="uploadframe"></iframe>
            </td>
            <td width="10" bgcolor="transparent" align="left" valign="middle">
                <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload">
            </td>
            <td width="245" bgcolor="transparent" align="left" valign="middle">
                <div id="progressNumber"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I need to start functions using JavaScript called respectively: `fileSelected()` & `uploadFile()`.
Or, is there another way to make a chosen file and upload button in pure JavaScript?

Comment: You already have event handler attributes set right. Are you asking for help writing the functions, or are you saying that they're not getting called as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..yes they work as expect but for other reason I need to call with JS! :)

Comment: Just to clarifiy then, you're asking how to call a JavaScript function from JavaScript?

Comment: mhhh...maybe is not clear exposed...so I have this two buttons located in formd id....table structure and they call these two js functions...I need to call these functions without method post formd id etc...just call from js after a certain event. I have already a function (in the same script) that check click mouse position and start a certain function. I have simply tried to call the two function in this way but had no luck...

Comment: Could you clarify "without method post formd id etc" and "but had no luck"?

Comment: using pure javascript to call these functions, in sense I have tried to call as normal js function but it did't work for me...
My goal is to restyle these two buttons in my js panel with a js function and not a structure like <form id>